# Spring boot, endpoints with connections to different servers using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following problem, I have a microservice in spring boot that, depending on the endpoint being consumed, must connect to a different server and database. I understand that using jdbc would make the problem easier, but currently the service is with jpa so the ideal solution would be with jpa but if it is not possible I would still like to see any solution that comes to mind, thank you very much for your attention

In my case, especially the endpoints will receive the parameters that require more the IP to connect and the database to create the connection and obtain the information, I cannot have in the datasource all the IPs and tables to which I must connect because it could be an infinite number, so I look for depending on the information that the client provides to connect to the server and database that I need.

Comment: What is the point of JPA in your case? Do you have @Entity classes defined or a structure in your business layer?

Comment: It has entities, it has several endpoints but as an example, one gets the type of store and the other the state of a flag, each one connects to a different server and database, these two endpoints will be consumed in sequence so You must connect to one server and then another to obtain the information and return a JSON with the response